# Is it possible and safe to combine MySQL syntax for INSERT INTO SET ánd ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (with the same column set)?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I know how the specific MySQL query syntax for `INSERT INTO SET` and `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` work. But, can you combine them? And... can you use the same `$columnSet` string (see below) for the `INSERT` and the `UPDATE` part, leaving the unique field in there?

Concider this example (I use php with pdo on my server):

```
// Define the query
$columnSet = "id=:id, date=:date, created=:created, modified=:modified, removed=:removed, synced=1, points=:points, comment=:comment";
$insertQuery = "INSERT INTO point_events SET"
               . $columnSet." ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ".$columnSet;

   // Define the data
    $pointData['id'] = 'someuniqueid not auto incremented';
$pointData['created'] = 1234; // a timestamp
$pointData['modified'] = 1234; // a timestamp
$pointData['removed'] = NULL;
$pointData['points'] = 10;
$pointData['comment'] = "A comment";
$pointData['date'] = time();

// Execute the query. pdoModify is custom function that executes the query.
pdoModify($pdoNew, $insertQuery, $oldData);
```

All posts I've seen do not combine these two syntaxes and all posts on `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` seem to suggest that you should not include the (duplicate) key in the string after `UPDATE`. So, is this safe, or could this behave differently / have unwanted side effects. Specifically leaving the unique id in the $columnSet for the UPDATE is what concerns me.

Comment: instead of using the entries twice, just use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE VALUES`

Comment: So for example, `DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=VALUES(id), date=VALUES(date)`, etc. Saves for a lot of parameterized input

Comment: OK. And then don't use INSERT INTO SET, but the normal INSERT INTO syntax? And having the id in the UPDATE statement is not a problem?

Comment: I don't know why you'd include the `id`, instead of just having an auto increment column for the id. Your insertion syntax is `INSERT INTO table(col1, col2) VALUES(:param1, :param2) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col1=VALUES(col1)....`. You can [read up more on the insert statement syntax here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: You don't need `id=VALUES(id)`, since `ON DUPLICATE KEY` they are equal. But it also doesn't hurt.

Comment: Well, being lazy is one reason :) (would have to write the insert values string and update values string separately -> which also introduces more room for mistakes). 2nd I prefer the INSERT INTO SET syntax better as it's less error prone in the sense that the column name and value are close together.

Comment: Note that using a placeholder (like `:date`) twice in a query only works when PDO emulates the prepared statements.

Comment: For lazy people (like you ;-)) there is a [REPLACE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your code should work. Typically, since the duplicate `id` unique key is initially checked, it is guaranteed than it will left unchanged when the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` clause is invoked.

However, this behavior is suboptimal (you are updating fields that are unchanged), and alos quite rigid: what if you need to increase the `amount` with the newly inserted value, or to concatenate the new `comment` at the end of thte existing one?

As commented by [Rogue](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1786065/rogue), MySQL syntax has a nice feature that allows the use of `VALUES(<some column>)` in the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` clause to refer to a value that was passed for `INSERT`. I would suggest to use that, since it is more elegant, and gives you much more control and flexibility.

Example:

```
$insertQuery = 
    "INSERT INTO point_events SET"
    . $columnSet
    ." ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE"
    ." modified =  VALUES(modified)"                  # replace this value
    .", synced = 1"                                  # assign a fixed value
    .", amount = amount + VALUES(amount)"             # add the new value
    .", comment = CONCAT(comment, ', ', VALUES(comment))"    # concatenante the new value
```

Comment: `VALUE()` will only work for [MariaDB 1.3.3](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/values-value/) and above. For MySQL you still need to use `VALUES()`.

Comment: Thanks Paul. I'm going to give the VALUES a try. Understand your point regarding the  'increasing' problem, but for me that's not applicable. All new values are provided to the php script. The suboptimal is a big one for me though... as this would be syncing logic for a mobile app... thus called many many times. Thanks!

Comment: @PaulSpiegel: thanks, I modified my answer accordingly.